# Windows 10 task bar crashing when opening explorer and some other applications?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1903

I am running on windows version **1903** and recently my windows crashing when I am opening the explorer, control-panel, task-manger..etc. When I open any of these applications, the task bar will go blank initially, hanging for few seconds and sometimes it may even go to the blue screen of death and re start the system.
And the interesting thing is I can open other application like chrome,teams,Vs-code,outlook..etc. and it works fine.
I tried safe mode as well but there is no difference.

Anyone facing similar kind of issue?

Comment: Can you open them while in Safe Mode.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 1):

Check the error code wich is given by the bluescreen.
Or try this [cmd sfc](https://support.microsoft.com/de-ch/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)
Also you could update your version.

Answer (score 0):

It got worked after updating to 2004 version of windows 10.